# Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea not always returning correct values

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, resolution

I am using `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` to place a popup window in the lower right corner of the primary screen. Normally, this works as it is intented to, but it has some issues when the application is being run on

- a computer that is connected to different screens with different resolutions (like a laptop being moved between offices).
- a computer that is an RDP server, which is connected to from clients with different resolutions (like a home computer being connected to from different offices).

It looks like the values of `WorkingArea` is not always up-to-date after having changed the resolution multiple (?) times in one of the above mentioned scenarios, which makes it difficult to correctly position the popup window.

Is there a way to force `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` to refresh, or is there any other ways of getting the screen resolution in a Windows Forms application that can be used instead?

Comment: I tested this in a test C#4.5 app on Win7 and after multiple screen resolution changes, up and down in scale, and all while the test app was running, I always got the correct size from `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`.  Is there more to the story?

Comment: Have you tried connecting with RDP? I am not completely sure when this happens, but it looks like it is when RDP or different screens are involved. I'll try the Pinvoke mentioned by TDull, and see if that gives other results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Pinvoke

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);

RECT scBounds = new RECT();
GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), ref scBounds);
```